# What is angle subtended by two consecutive points on the circumference at the centre?

Tags: geometry, circles, angle

A circle is continuous and yet when you take two consecutive points it seems as if the angle subtended at the centre is zero. If there was some angle between them how could they be consecutive? Tell me if am thinking wrong.

Comment: Indeed: How could they be consecutive in the first place?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen but then can't I approximate the two points to be one?

Comment: How are you defining "consecutive" for two points on a circle? Let's even consider a simpler problem: if you have two "consecutive" points on a line, then what is the distance between them?

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician that would conviniently tend to zero as two adjacent points essentially touch each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your "thinking is wrong", but in an old and respectable way.

The usual version of this (wrong) way of thinking is that on the number line there's a "next number" after any particular number. But that's not the case. There is no "next number" after $0$. To see why, suppose that next number is $t$. Then where would you put $t/2$, which is in between $0$ and $t$?

Mathematicians and philosophers have struggled with this problem since Zeno and the Greeks: you can read about [Zeno's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes)  many places. Mathematicians have figured out over the years how to deal with questions like yours.

Your concern about "adjacent points" on a circle is essentially the same. It's a good question.

Comment: So you are saying that truly adjacent points are undefined, i.e, they can't be certainly expressed by a number. But that doesn't mean they don't exist, right?

Comment: @AmyanshuJenamani You said it yourself, "truly adjacent" points are "undefined" because there is no way to define them so that they behave "nicely", in the "expected way" of "adjacent points". In short, they do not exist. Your argument is basically that you agree when looking at numbers, but not when looking at points. The problem is that in this context, a point can be defined as a (pair of) number(s), so number properties extend to point properties. And what number properties say, is that in a continuum, there is no good notion of "adjacent".

Comment: @Amyanshu, as noted, there really is no mathematically satisfactory way to define terms like "adjacent" or "consecutive" in this context. Another way of expressing what N. Bach is saying is that one can always map numbers to points on a line (think of the number line) or a circle (think of angles in radian measure), so any property that applies to numbers (e.g. "adjacency" not being well-defined) maps to a corresponding property that applies to points, and vice-versa.

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician So a good way to conclude this answer would be to say it's "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

For calculation of circumference C we calculate the distance between two subsequent point which the angle between their connecting lines to the center( two radii) is$d t$.We have:

$ C =\int^{2\pi}_0 r dt=r [ t ]^{2\pi}_0 =2\pi r$

How can we calculate C if there is no distance $rdt$ between two points or the angle between two connecting lines to center is zero?If there is no distance between them then they are coincident not consecutive!

Comment: That's essentially my own doubt. What value will you give to the angle subtended by two consecutive points at the centre? If it ain't zero then it is something that tends to zero and infinitely so. Two adjacent points touch each other and if there was any angle between between the lines joining them then there would be atleast an infintesimal separation between them. That would contradict them being consecutive.

Comment: What value will you give to the separation between two consecutive points given a point has no dimensions?

Comment: What is difference between coincident and consecutive or  adjacent.?When you say consecutive you mean next one which contains a sort of physical difference meaning anyway. You talk about another point in another location not the same point coincident with previous one. The distance theoretically achieves zero when the number of points are infinity but it is actually not zero.

Comment: It's actually undefined as it has no proper physical significance. Refer the answer above.

Comment: Due to this speculation there would be no line too because a line is contracted of infinite points. These abstract definitions , like point or line or imaginary numbers has of course no physical meaning but help us to solve realistic problems. When you say consecutive, you apply a physical meaning to it which is also an abstract or imaginary definition.

Comment: A line is perfectly fine until you decide to find two adjacent points on it or try to describe it as a collection of infinite points (infinity is a dangerous realm and it serves no purpose in solving real world problems). It's the definition of a point itself which makes the situation trickier. A point can be described with the help of numbers on a complex plane. So the properties of numbers extends to them. And for numbers you can always find a closer next number, which is why adjacency is not well defined in this case.

Comment: A limiting case would find the adjacent points coinciding. But to think of truly adjacent points (with no dimensions) is impossible.